# What is the specific task a singleton pattern accomplishes at the time it is handed .this?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

Trying to get a handle on what the singleton pattern is, and what it's for. I think I'm close, but I'm not quite sure. I understand we use this technique when we only want one instance of a certain thing. But I haven't gotten my head around what that means and what the code part actually does.

FOR ANALOGY ONLY: Let's say I own a store with only one cash register. Employees and customers are scripts. I want every employee and customer in the building to use that one register for checkout related tasks. (I think that's what singleton is for)

```
 public class cashRegister
 {
     public static cashRegister TheeOneAndOnlyCashRegister;

     void Start()
     {
     }

     void Update()
     {        
     }

     void Awake()
     {
         if (TheeOneAndOnlyCashRegister == null)
             TheeOneAndOnlyCashRegister = this;
     }
 }
```

So what I don't understand is what I actually did here (if I even did this correctly).

Did I tell the store that there must be 'this' register in existence?
Or did I tell the store that all people can only ever use this register?
Or did I merely just name the register a name and demand the name was TheeOneAndOnlyCashRegister?

Comment: If you have 3 instances of `cashRegister` They're all sharing the same instance of `TheeOneAndOnlyCashRegister`.  So when you set `TheeOneAndOnlyCashRegister = this;` in one instance of `cashRegister`, they're all using that same `TheeOneAndOnlyCashRegister `. You're example is too simple to see the benefit of this, that's probably why it's so confusing.

Comment: Very nice [article](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton) about singleton from Jon Skeet

Comment: @Train So what does the last code block actually do in relation to the three instances of 'cashRegister'? Can you clarify in more detail?

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski - I can't tell which example in the Jon Skeet Article is comparable to the one I attempted to use. Can you clarify?

Comment: It makes sure that you only have 1 instance of cashRegister when you call awake(). but one thing it does it allows for non static methods, so each instance of `cashRegister` doesn't have to share the `start() or update()` methods. Again this example is too simple to see the benefit in this, this is a pretty specific scenario so unless you can see a real life example of this it won't make much sense to you.

Comment: You should avoid using singletons at all, it behaves like a global variable makes unit testing difficult or impossible. Use dependency injection instead.

Comment: @PavelStepanets - being new to this stuff, it seems logical to try and understand what something does, in order for the reasons why to NOT do make sense. I've noted that it's unpopular, but since people do seem to use it, I figured it couldn't hurt to learn a thing or two about it. ...I have no idea what dependency injection is, but I'll keep that in mind as I learn more about patterns.